# XPath to get <input>s belonging to a specific html form

Tags: html, xpath

How do I pick up `<input>`s *belonging* to a certain `<form>` using XPath?  By *belonging*, I mean input where the `.form` attribute in JavaScript equals the specific form instance.

In the general case, I want an XPath that returns the same inputs this JavaScript returns:

```
Array.prototype.filter.call(document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    function(x) { return x.form == f1; })
```

**Note: This does not mean *is-a-child-of* w.r.t. the DOM-tree!**

For example, given the following (malformed) html:

```
<html>
<body>
  <table>
    <form name="foo">
    <input name="bar"/>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="baz"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </form>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

`bar.form == foo` and `baz.form == foo` hold true, but the DOM-tree can be generated in a way that `"//form[@name='foo']//input"` contains neither `bar` nor `baz`.

e.g. Chrome/Firefox/IE will produce this DOM-tree for the above source:

```
<html>
<head/>
<body>
  <input name="foo"/>
  <table>
    <form name="bar"></form>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input name="baz"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S. An acceptable answer could simply state why this isn't possible.

*Edit: Clarified the meaning of the bottom example.  Updated the example to show why simply traversing the DOM-tree will not work.*

Comment: Why are you working with such horribly malformed HTML?

Comment: Malformed HTML is going to screw up DOM parsers... but are you looking to [simply select inputs with name="bar"](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/6bf46003560ce222e7d1179f3430b430)?

Answer (score 0):

With the examples you posted, I don't see this possible. You would do this with an event based (SAX) parser, where you keep the name of the "last seen form name" and allocate each input element to that form.
Of course, especially for the second example, this isn't how the browser sees it.

Since I can't use comments yet:
@dirkk: preceding won't work, because the axis is "excluding any ancestors". So for the valid HTML case, it actually doesn't work, as a form is considered an ancestor. It's a good idea though, maybe `preceding|ancestor` will work.

Comment: There aren't two input examples. The html below "e.g." was meant to describes the DOM-tree that a conventional browser produces if fed the first html.  I've made edits to clarify this, and changed the examples to show why I don't think DOM-tree traversal would work.  I was hoping there might be some provision in XPath to handle this "owning-form" notion, like a function.. but probably there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is invalid HTML. Form inputs have to be inside a `<form/>` element, otherwise it is not clear how they correlate. For example, in the following HTML snippet, how should a browser or any HTML parser now to which form the input belongs:

```
<table>
  <form name="foo"></form>
  <form name="foo2"></form>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="bar" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

That being said, many browser are very relaxed and basically allow HTML designers to not use any standard. So they could use metric and say each input belongs to the last preceding form element. Maybe their heuristic is more elaborate, so you might not get each and every corner-case with this. However, the following XPath should work at least for your two examples:

```
//input[(preceding::form)[last()]/@name="foo"]
```

This way, you get all input elements, which had as last form element the one with the specified name, in this case *foo*.

Comment: There aren't two input examples.  The html below "e.g." describes the DOM-tree that a conventional browser (Chrome/IE/Firefox) produces if fed the first html.

Comment: I've made edits to clarify this, and changed the example to show why I don't think this can be solved by simple DOM-tree traversing conditions.